# How to umount a USB key while running on tails

Tags: boot, usb, bootable, lsblk, tails-os

I would like to create a live USB from TAILS (on the same USB key as that of running TAILS). A dd from the iso to the device is not tolerated since the key is mounted:

```
$ lsblk

sdb       8:16   1   7.5G  0 disk 
└─sdb1    8:17   1     4G  0 part /lib/live/mount/medium
```

and naturally

```
umount: /lib/live/mount/medium: target is busy.
```

**How to have the TAILS USB key unmounted in order to create a bootable usb key on it**

Comment: I don't quite understand the question: Do you want to overwrite the stick while Tails OS is running from it, or do you want to *clone* the running Tails OS to another stick?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `toram` as a boot parameter.